# finding the limit superior of a sequence involving fractional part

Tags: radicals, limsup-and-liminf, fractional-part

I'm stuck with this exercise that's asking to prove that:

$$\limsup_n\{\sqrt n\}=1$$

I've managed to prove that the limit inferior is $0$ but I've failed to prove this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $0\leq \{x\}<1$ for any real $x$, it follows that
$$\limsup_n\,\{\sqrt n\}\leq 1$$
In order to show the equality, it suffices to find a sequence of  positive integers $(n_k)_k$ such that $n_k\to +\infty$ and $\{\sqrt n_k\}\to 1$.

Take $n_k:=k^2-1$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$. Then $k-1\leq \sqrt{k^2-1}< k$ implies that, as $k\to\infty$,
\begin{align*}
\{\sqrt{n_k}\}&=\sqrt{k^2-1}-(k-1)=k\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k^2}}-k+1\\
&=k\left(1-\frac{1}{2k^2}+o(1/k^2)\right)-k+1=1+o(1)\to 1
\end{align*}
where we used the fact that $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}+o(x)$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @Renato Faraone Any further doubt?

Comment: no, perfect answer thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\sqrt{k²+2k}-k=\frac{2k}{\sqrt{k^2+2k}+k}$$

Comment: How does this help me ?

Comment: For $n=k^2+2k$, what is $\{\sqrt{n}\}$ ?